# Complexity of an algorithm with two cases

Tags: algorithms

What is the complexity for following algorithm if

1) $f(i, j) = (j - 1)\ \&\ j$

2) $f(i, j) = (j - 1)\ \&\ i$

```
s = 0

for(i = 0; i <= pow(2, n); i++){

    for(j = i; j > 0; j = f(i, j)) {
        s++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is almost unreadable. Please use "insert code" and use indentation in your code. I suppose & is for "and" operator. What I would do is find value of $f(i,j)$ by making cases, this will enable you to find the number of times the "s++" line is executed...

Comment: As an example, for case 1), suppose $j=*...*10...0=m.2^{k+1}+1.2^k$. Put it like this : $k$ is the position of the first bit set to $1$ in the binary notation of $j$. Then you find $j-1=*...*01...1$, so $(j-1)\& j=*...*00...0=m.2^{k+1}$. Use $k$ (and $m$) to categorize the cases.

Comment: Yes, & is for 'and ' operator

Comment: Can you detail, please for second case?

Comment: As Nicolas mentioned, if you get an understanding of what $j=f(i,j)$ does, it should make your life simpler. In the first case, that assignment sets the least significant non-zero bit of $j$ to $0$. So computing the complexity boils down to solving some combinatorics problem. Unfortunately in the second case, fully explaining what the assignment does nearly completely solves the problem. As a hint, notice that any bit position that is $0$ in $i$ will also always be $0$ in $j$.

Comment: BTW, are you sure the end condition in the internal loop is not "j>0" ? Because if j is unsigned, this could go forever... But maybe it's simply that I don't understand C code...

Comment: I changed y > 0

Comment: For case 1, I found that s is $\frac{1}{2}(2^{n}n + 2)$. Is it ok?

Comment: Look at my first answer (the second will arrive when my ideas are clear on the subject).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second case, let's explore an example : let's choose $i=203=11001011_2$, we find the following sequence for $j$ :

$11001011$

$11001010$

$11001001$

$11001000$

$11000011$

$11000010$

$11000001$

$11000000$

$10001011$

etc

So everything is as if the zeroes where ignored : you count from $x$ to $0$, where $x$ is written whit only the ones in the binary writing of $i$.

If $i$ has $k$ bits set to $1$, then $x=2^k-1$ is the time spent in the inner loop. So the complexity is
$$1+\sum_k=0^n (2^k-1)\binom nk = 1+\sum_k=0^n 2^k\binom nk - \sum_k=0^n \binom nk = 1 + (1+2)^n - 2^n = 3^n+1-2^n$$
Hope my analysis is correct.

Comment: Yes, it is correct! Nice solution, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, the inner loop runs forever because `j` remains stuck at 0.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the first case : as was said in the comments, $f(i,j)=(j-1)\& j$ consists in changing the lest significant bit set to $1$ in $j$ to $0$. So repeating operation $j=f(i,j)$ until $j=0$ does erase the $1$ bits of $j$ from right to left, you make as many passages in the loop as there are bits set to $1$ in $j$.

As $j$ is initially $i$ in the inner loop, you have to count the number of bits set to $1$ in $i$. As $i$ goes from $0$ to $2^n-1$, $i$ has $n$ bits. The number of $i$ for which the binary form contains $k$ bits set to $1$ is $\binom nk$, for you have to choose the places of the ones. For those $i$, the inner loop is executed $k$ times. So the number of times the instruction $s++$ is executed is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k.\binom nk = \sum_{k=1}^n n.\binom{n-1}{k-1} = n\sum_{k'=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k'} = n.2^{n-1}$$
to which you have to add $1$ because the upper bound is $2^n$, not $2^n-1$, so there is one more iteration for $i=2^n$.

The second case is a little bit more difficult, but you can benefit from the fact that the initial value of $j$ is $i$. So the first time, the rightmost bit set to one in $j$ is set to $0$. After that, you have to figure out what will happen. The loop must end at some time, because $(j-1)\& i\le j-1<j$. Study some example to figure out how many times the inner loop is executed.